# AJAX post request using qwest.js to goo.gl url shortener api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-url-shortener

I am trying to shorten a URL using goo.gl URL Shortener API an open source library ([qwest.js](https://github.com/pyrsmk/qwest)). I've achieved it successfully using jquery though, but its giving me error "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input." when done using qwest.

My code with jquery :

```
var longURL = "http://www.google.com/";
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIzaSyANFw1rVq_vnIzT4vVOwIw3fF1qHXV7Mjw',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
        data: '{ longUrl:"'+ longURL+'"}',         
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response)
        }
 })
.done(function(res) {
    console.log("success"); 
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

and the non-working code with qwest.js

```
var longURL = "http://www.google.com/"    
qwest.post('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=479dfb502221d2b4c4a0433c600e16ba5dc0df4e&',
    {longUrl: longURL}, 
    {responseType:'application/json; charset=utf-8'})
                    .then(function(response) {
                        // Make some useful actions
                    })
                    .catch(function(e, url) {
                        // Process the error
                    });
```

any help would be highly recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author of qwest here ;)

As stated in the docs : `the default Content-Type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded for post and xhr2 data types, with a POST request`.

But Google Shortener service does not accept it. I assume it wants a JSON input type. Then you should set the `dataType` option of qwest to `json`. Furthermore, your `responseType` option is invalid and does not follow the docs. Normally, you don't have to set it if Google replies to request with a valid `Content-Type` header. Here's the good code :

`qwest.post('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=479dfb502221d2b4c4a0433c600e16ba5dc0df4e&',
    {longUrl: longURL}, 
    {dataType:'json'})`

In the case where Google does not send a recognized `Content-Type`, just set the `responseType` option to `json` too.

Comment: hi there! 
thanks for{ dataType:'json'} . it worked.
i also noticed i was using a wrong key too (different thing)
good plugin

Comment: Thanks! Glad you've fixed your problem

Comment: Can we make synchronous calls using qwest like we do using ajax?

Comment: Yes, we can, by setting the `async` option to `false`.